# Change Product Rankings in Category View

Tags: product-attribute, category-products

I'm trying to change the order of products that appear on the category view page. The searchindex_weight attribute works to reorder searches, but it has no bearing on the listing in the category view. So far, I've come up with nothing that I can change that will affect it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In category page assign product weight for each product then do indexing. This will solve the problem.

Comment: In the category page? As in 'Manage Categories' on the admin side? I don't see a product weight option.